# Linux exec program not getting outputted values

Tags: c++, mercurial, cmake, fedora

Not sure why this isn't working...the following cmake script works well on windows:

```
exec_program(hg ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGREMOTEDIR}
ARGS "log" "-r" ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HG_HASH_CODE} "--template" "{latesttag}"
OUTPUT_VARIABLE ${PROJECT_NAME}_HG_LAST_TAG)
```

which gets the latest tag. However, in Fedora 17, when I try to run the `${PROJECT_NAME}_HG_LAST_TAG` ends up empty.

My first thought was that the repository location was somehow wrong. So I tried to run:

```
exec_program(hg ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGREMOTEDIR}
ARGS "log" "-r" ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HG_HASH_CODE}
OUTPUT_VARIABLE ${PROJECT_NAME}_HG_LAST_TAG)
```

This fills in `${PROJECT_NAME}_HG_LAST_TAG` with:

```
changeset:   368:a7ab3c8aca83
branch:      Integration
tag:         tip
user:        ******
date:        Wed Dec 11 10:59:33 2013 -0500
summary:     ******
```

so then I thought maybe "latesttag" wasn't supported..But latest tag "works" in a terminal.

```
>hg log -r a7ab3c8aca83 --template "{latesttag}"
2.0>
```

So my last though was that for some reason, the --template command makes it bad. So I made a template with no outside data

> hg log -r a7ab3c8aca83 --template foo

and then in the CMake file

```
exec_program(hg ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGREMOTEDIR}
ARGS "log" "-r" ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HG_HASH_CODE} "--template" "foo"
OUTPUT_VARIABLE ${PROJECT_NAME}_HG_LAST_TAG)
```

and `${PROJECT_NAME}_HG_LAST_TAG` is still empty. What would cause this? Is there a work around?

Comment: First sanity check: Does `hg --version` show the same output from cmake as it does from your command line?

Comment: It does...I think I figured it out. I'll put it in an answer below, it appears to be a bug with cmake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug in CMake: the output variable will not add parts of a stream that do not end in a new-line.

exec_program(cat ARGS test OUTPUT_VARIABLE TEST_VAR)

if test doesn't end in a new line, the TEST_VAR isn't filled in, despite a valid output in a shell terminal.

If test ends in a new line, then the output is filled in.

The fix, in my case, is to change the template to include a newline:

```
exec_program(hg ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HGREMOTEDIR}
ARGS "log" "-r" ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HG_HASH_CODE} "--template" "\"{latesttag}\\n\""
OUTPUT_VARIABLE ${PROJECT_NAME}_HG_LAST_TAG)
```

And then the code works (in both windows and linux).